# JSON parsed Messages do not display on page using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Below I have mentioned question related script from .JS & .PHP pages to make question as much shorter and cleaner as possible.

If I submit form after entering correct email and secret code on form page, it inserts data in database table. If I submit form after entering incorrect email and/or secret code on form page, it doesn't inserts data in database table due to server side validation script I have written. So script part is working properly.

I am able to alert success / error messages on **.js** page when I use **alert(data);**. But these messages do not display on page when I try to print them for visitor. Below is sample message I am getting in alert box.

```
{"status":"OK","message":"Inserted successfully"}
```

What should I do to display these messages on page? Please let me know.

***Client Side Page (contact.js)***

```
$.ajax({
url: "./contact_p.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
    emailid: emailid,
        secretcode: secretcode
},
cache: false,

success: function() {
//alert(data);
// Success message
$responsetext=JSON.parse(data);    

if($responseText.staus=='OK')
{
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-success')
    .append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " </strong>");
    $('#success > .alert-success')
    .append('</div>');
}
else if($responseText.status=='ERR')
{
    // Fail message
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " ");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
}
},
```

***Server Side page (contact_p.php)***

```
if( empty($str_r_email) || validateEmail($str_r_email)==false )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalid Email ID!";
    echo json_encode($response); 
    return ;
}
if( empty($str_r_secretcode) || $_SESSION['image_secret_code'] !=    $str_r_secretcode )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalid Secrete Code!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return ;
}

$str_insert = "INSERT INTO t_contact (emailid,idate,ipaddress) VALUES('".$str_emailid."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
RunQuery($str_insert);
$response['status']='OK';
$response['message']='Inserted successfully';
echo json_encode($response);
return ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to parse json. Just try this code for your success function.

```
success: function(res) {
if(res.staus=='OK')
{
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-success')
    .append("<strong> " + res.message + " </strong>");
    $('#success > .alert-success')
    .append('</div>');
}
else if(res.status=='ERR')
{
    // Fail message
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong> " + res.message + " ");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
}
}
```

Comment: Ty for your reply but no message displays yet after using your suggested code... Also do I need to make any changes at contact_p.php (server side page) if I use your above code? Please let me know.

Comment: alert `res.staus` and tell me what value it gives you.

Comment: Ty, I will check and let you know about response.

Comment: It is giving 'undefined' message in alert box.

Answer (score 1):

Dude the variable `$responsetext=JSON.parse(data);`  is in PHP it should have been `var responsetext=JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Ty, it works now after making your suggested change. But there is another new issue. When I enter any incorrect details, script throws me proper error message. But secret code image still remains same (old) one. So after first error message, whenever I enter correct details and press submit button, it just gives me Invalid Secret Code issue. Please let me know if you can help me anything to resolve this issue.

Comment: what do you mean by same (old) one?, sorry i got lost XD

Comment: is that some sortof captcha?

Comment: yes, it is captacha... sorry for my poor explanation... I guess this is reason of issue but I have no clue to resolve it. During all these submissions, contact.php page is not refreshed so new captcha is not generated by PHP and whenever I submit form, PHP reset captcha value to NULL at server side (on contact_p.php) so both captcha values do not match with each other. I hope this time I have explained proper.

Comment: try to add timestamp or `time();` at the end of your `image` captcha.

<img src='imgs/sample.jpg?any=" . time() . "' />

Comment: I assume that the correct hidden value is correct already and you have only issue on the image loading.

Comment: it just updates the browser's `cache` so the image won't be stagnant.

Comment: no success yet after making above mentioned changes.

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP returns a `Content-Type: application/json` header then AJAX automatically gives a JSON object in your success function (your forgot to write `data` parameter in `success`, don't know if it's a typo or not).

If you have no `Content-Type: application/json` header, then add `dataType: "JSON"` in your ajax call, like so :

```
$.ajax({
url: "./contact_p.php",
type: "POST",
dataType: "JSON",
data: {
    emailid: emailid,
        secretcode: secretcode
},
cache: false,

success: function(data) {
//alert(data);
// Success message
var $responsetext=data;    

if($responseText.staus=='OK')
{
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-success')
    .append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " </strong>");
    $('#success > .alert-success')
    .append('</div>');
}
else if($responseText.status=='ERR')
{
    // Fail message
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " ");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
}
```

Comment: ty for your response. Now I am able to print message properly. But there is another new issue. When I entered any incorrect details, script throws me proper error message. But secret code image still remains same (old) one. So after first error message, whenever I enter correct details and submit button, it just gives me Invalid Secret Code issue. Please let me know if you can help me anything to resolve this issue. It will be very helpful.


Please let me know if you can help with that.